# how to show image contents on mouse over on the image?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to implement same as on this website  [click here](http://www.infosys.com/pages/index.aspx)

```
$(function() {
  $('#div_2').hide();
  $('#div_1, #div_2').hover(function() {
      $('#div_2').stop().fadeIn(120); 
       $("div_2").animate({left:"100px"},"slow");
    $("div_2").animate({fontSize:"3em"},"slow"); 
  }, function(){
      $('#div_2').stop().fadeOut();

  });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="div_1" style="background-position:top;position:relative">
        <img src="spotlights-infytalk (1).jpg" width="329" height="110" style="position:relative;vertical-align:top"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div_2" style=" overflow:auto;position:relative;padding-top:-10px;background-color:#CCCCCC">
image small few contents text
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

give **title="image content"** to your img tag. like :

```
<img src="" title="image content" />
```

also use **alt** attribute in img tag, it will create good impact for seo.

Comment: What you said is correct. But that is not the solution of my problem.